# Issue in server because of infinite loop in the php page

Tags: php

I am working on a php site and I have uploaded a php file contains infinite loop (I didn't noticed it).After uploaded that file the server is hanged and now i can't connect to the server.How to solve this issue.

Comment: it'll time out (at least it should), you should still be able to FTP in and take the file off.

Comment: kolink and @kennypu answer/comment  is way to go ,,,, but your problem loled me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should die after 60 seconds, unless you changed or removed the time limit. Otherwise, if you have shell access you can kill the process.

Comment: I am trying for one hour but can't connect to the server

Comment: have you tried by removing file by ftp ?

Answer (score 0):

it would definitely die after the time limit. however if you **restart/reset services** of webserver and php on your server . it would be resolved.

Comment: so how it possible when user dont have access to restart server